# Move minus sign from right to left?

Tags: python, regex

I have a number `'24.45-'` and wanted to move the minus sign from right to left like `'-24.45'` in Python.I am dealing with huge data in data frame and trying to do this using regex so that I can apply on the whole column. Tried this but with no luck, any suggestions please.

```
print(re.sub(r"([0-9.]+)((\W$))","\2\1","24.45-"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like this:

```
>>> n = '24.45-'
>>> n = n[-1] + n[:-1]
>>> n
'-24.45'
>>>
```

Comment: list = ["24.45-", "3123123.123123-", '3-']
print([i[-1] + i[:-1] for i in list])